# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when starting xampp control panel

Tags: windows, dll

Iam facing this .dll error and I can't solve it.

> This programme can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

When Iam opening XAMPP Control Panel

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of xampp this error came.

- you can use older version to get ride from this error.
- or you can Update your Windows Version to the most Current.
- or Download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Re distributable Update 3. You may need to download the x64 and x86 versions. [(LINK TO MICROSOFT PAGE)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587)
- or If you're not using Windows 10, you could also try updating your Universal C Runtime for Windows ([LINK TO MICROSOFT PAGE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows))

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to downgrade and download 
 [**PHP 5.6.39**](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
Or 
 [**PHP 7.0.3**](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

There are lot of solution available but most of them don't work.